# Find Text in a HTML-Element and add an icon (gylphicon) with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to find a specific text in a Element (e.g `<label>`) in a HTML-Code and add a Bootstrap-Glyphicon next to it with a specific link.

Example:

```
<label>Link1</label>
```

it should be like this:

```
<label>Link1</label>
<a href="Link1.html">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
</a>
```

I think i need a jQuery-Script to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with this single line of jquery.

First use `$("label:contains('Link1')")` to find the label containing the particular text. then insert the html after that element using `insertAfter function`.

**checkout**

```js
$('<a href="Link1.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>').insertAfter($("label:contains('Link1')"));
```

```html
<label id="link" >Link1</label>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newLink = $('<a></a>').attr('href', 'link1');
var newSpan = $('<span></span>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-question-mark');
newLink.append(newSpan);

$('label').after(newLink);
```

This is jQuery and uses jQuery methods to build the link element you described and add it in after the label. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need Jquery to solve it. and solution is simple, hope this helps you :)

```
<label>Link1</label>
```

Jquery:

```
$('<a href="Link1.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>').insertAfter( "label:contains('Link1')" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will work!

```
(function() {
  $('label').each(function() {
    var link = '<a href="' + $(this).text() + '.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>';
    $(this).after().append(link);
  });
})();
```